# how to start earnign bitcoin?

Tags: learning, earnings

I have email id and linux OS(Ubuntu, Fedora). I use internet through ISP.
I am also a CSE student that means I know programming. How can I earn bitcoin and where should I start?

I need short and straightforward step for this?

Comment: Replace 'bitcoin' in your question with 'dollars', and the answer will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

How do I get rich without showing any proof of work? This made me down vote. Might be the wrong area to raise such question...

If it is really an honest question, then you might want to start at bitcoin.org, and read the book mastering bitcoin (https://www.transifex.com/bitcoinbook/mastering-bitcoin/) from Andreas.

Then precise your question and come back?